# When I try to validate 'username' field in Django form with clean_method I get a NameError

Tags: python, django, validation

Here is my forms.py file. I got a "NameError: name 'username' is not defined" on this row:

`def clean_username(self):`

trying to submit this form, but, AFAIK, there are nothing wrong with it.

```
from .models import Blog
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.exception import ValidationError

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('title', 'description',)

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150) #, help_text='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150) #, help_text='Last Name')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required. Enter a valid email address')

    def clean_username(self):
        nom_de_guerre=self.cleaned_data['username']
        if User.objects.filter(username=nom_de_guerre).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('User with this name is already exists!')
        return nom_de_guerre

    def clean_email(self):
        addresse_de_mail=self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.object.filter(email=addresse_de_mail).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('User with this email is already exists!')
        return addresse_de_mail

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
```

Here is my view where I use this form:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = '''Activate your Bard's Lair Account'''
            message = render_to_string('blog/activation_request.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('activation_sent_view')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/signup.html', {'form': form}
```

And here is my full traceback:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://www.bards-lair.com/signup/

Django Version: 4.0
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'portfolio',
 'markdownx']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mougrim/simple_django3_blog/django3blogenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mougrim/simple_django3_blog/django3blogenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mougrim/simple_django3_blog/blog/views.py", line 56, in user_signup
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/home/mougrim/simple_django3_blog/django3blogenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 190, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/mougrim/simple_django3_blog/django3blogenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 185, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/mougrim/simple_django3_blog/django3blogenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 404, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/home/mougrim/simple_django3_blog/django3blogenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 419, in _clean_fields
    value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
  File "/home/mougrim/simple_django3_blog/blog/forms.py", line 19, in clean_username
    def clean_username(self):

Exception Type: NameError at /signup/
Exception Value: name 'username' is not defined
```

Comment: in the clean method you have to return the cleaned value  in your method you don't return  a value

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis I've corrected this, thanks, but error, alas, still persists :(

Comment: @VitaliyHristyuk: did you by any chance update the `clean_username` method. It looks like you use `username` as a variable, but that variable is never defined.

Comment: @WillemVanOnselm Nope, I did not, and because of that I absolutely confused - i've just added clean methods to my form and got this error :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the (cleaned) value in case it is valid, so:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150) #, help_text='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150) #, help_text='Last Name')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required. Enter a valid email address')
    
    def clean_username(self):
        nom_de_guerre = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if User.objects.filter(username=nom_de_guerre).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('User with this name is already exists!')
        return nom_de_guerre

    def clean_email(self):
        addresse_de_mail = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.object.filter(email=addresse_de_mail).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('User with this email is already exists!')
        return addresse_de_mail

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, this is a valid point, only it didn't help any with my error :(

Comment: @VitaliyHristyuk: can you edit the question and show the view where you use the form and the full traceback?

Comment: @WillemVanOnselm Thank you, I've added view and full traceback.